# Accesing a 2d array like this? array[ 0 ][ j ] to check all the values from the first row?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program that checks if there is a '*' in the border in a file with an array of characters.

Example:

```
......* <-- in the border
.......
.......
*...... <-- also in the border
```

I tried using a nested loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++)
             for (int j = 0; j < cell[i].length; j++)
             { 
                if (cell[0][j] == '*' || cell[39][j] == '*'|| cell[i][0] == '*' || cell[i][59] == '*')
                   system.out.print("We messed up boyz")
              }
```

Now that is supposed to check for the first row and the last row, but the actual behavior is that it takes any value for the row position, not the 0 position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply this rules for each border, you could use a condition that matches with any border index value :

```
 if (i == 0 || i== rowMaxIndex  || j == 0 || j == columnMaxIndex) ) {
      .. // I check the star
  }
```

where `rowMaxIndex` is the max index of the first dimension (rows) and where `columnMaxIndex` is the max index of the second dimension (columns).

Here is the code :

```
 int rowMaxIndex = cell.length - 1;
 int columnMaxIndex = cell[0].length - 1;

 for (int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){ 
   for (int j = 0; j < cell[i].length; j++){ 
      if ( cell[i][j] == '*' && 
         (i == 0 || i == rowMaxIndex  || j == 0 || j == columnMaxIndex) ){
            System.out.print("We messed up boyz");
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hello David, but I try to check for all the '*' in the border, that means First row, Last Row, First Column and Last Column. Would I need 4 loops in that case? Thanks beforehand

Comment: Hello Luis. Not necessarily. I updated to give a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if (cell[0][j] == '*') -> checks the row

if (cell[0][0] == '*') -> checks the first position

You only want to check 1 position? didn't understand correctly

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment to clarify the question before answering it.

Comment: Hello G. Fonseca, now I try to check if there is '*' on the border of the array, so First Column, Last Column, First row and last row